# How do I get a folder displayed in TreeView Qt

Tags: c++, qt, treeview

I have a TreeView in a QtGui. But I want it to display only one folder at `'F:\Qt\GUI\files'`
I have tries a tutorial on youtube (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M0PZDrDwdHM) but I read on qt-project.org that QDirModel is obselete now. And I don't know how to do this now. The end result needs to be the same as in the youtube video but than without all the other drives and folders on the pc.

Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to use [QFileSystemModel](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qfilesystemmodel.html) instead of QDirModel. To set directory you want to be displayed use the [setRootPath](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qfilesystemmodel.html#setRootPath) method. For example, to display MyComputer content use an empty string as a parameter value.

Comment: so if I want to show only one folder with this path `F:/Qt/GUI/files` I should use something like this?
`model->setRootPath("F:/Qt/GUI/files");`

Comment: You should use next code: `model->setRootPath("F:/Qt/GUI/files"); treeView->setModel(model); treeView->setRootIndex(model->index("F:/Qt/GUI/files"));`